# Need assistance with Android || operator

Tags: java, android

I want to say, 'Search for the user's name OR the user's number, but this doesn't work :

```
if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())   
    .contains(charText)) || (wp.getPhone().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())  
    .contains(charText))
```

Any ideas on how I could get this working? Here's my full code :

```
 public void filter(String charText) {
            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    //        _data is our list of contacts
            _data.clear();
    //        If there is nothing in the searchview, if the charText length is 0,
    //        then show all the contacts
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
                _data.addAll(arraylist);
    //            or else....
            } else {
                for (SelectContact wp : arraylist) {
    //                If a contact's name matches the input thus far, which is charText, or their number matches it,
    //                then include it in the listview.
                    if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                            .contains(charText)) || (wp.getPhone().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                            .contains(charText))
                         {

                            _data.add(wp);
                        }
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: Enclose ALL your if condidtion inside parentheses `if ((...) || (...))`. Now it is `if (...) || (...)`, which won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bob Malooga pointed out in his comment above, always enclose the **whole** of your if condition in brackets, like this

```
if (put the whole condition of what your looking out for in here)
{do stuff}
```